# Node & Express Endpoint always returns 200

Tags: node.js, rest

I am having issues with a block of code in my node.js API. I have a simple JWT authentication API that is working as expected in terms of logging in and authentication. Howvever I cannot get express to return a response status other then 200.

If I enter an invalid username or password for the login end point, the response I receive is an empty 200 response, despite the fact the below code executes the catch block, and I return a response of 500 with my error. from the post method. This is getting lost somewhere, and converted to the empty 200 response. On succesfull login the `return res.status(200).json....` code returns the correct response.

I have the same issue on all endpoints, all error responses are return as an empty 200 response.

Could any one advise.

```
app.post('/user/login', async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.user.email;
    const password = req.body.user.password;
    try {
      const authServiceInstance = new AuthService();
      const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.Login(email, password);
      return res.status(200).json({ user, token }).end();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Error in login: ', e);
      return res.json(e).status(500).end();
    }
  })
```

Comment: Function works like you wrote it and it is executed line by line. It doesnt wait on the authServiceInstance.Login() and executes the next line with the response: 200 and empty values

Comment: I disagree... if I change the code to

```      
const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.Login(email, password);
console.log("done auth");
return res.status(200).json({ user, token }).end();
```
Then the new line of text is not printed, and the console definitely shows Erro in login... which says the error being thrown by authService.Login is being caught as I mentioned in my orignal post. So I am pretty confident the return is status 500 not status 200